# Formula to calculate overtime hours not working consistently

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

**Edit: It now calculates overtime after implementing Vincent's solution in the comments**

My girlfriend works from home 6 hours a day and gets to make her own hours. She asked me to make a time sheet for her that she can enter her start and end times into and will automatically calculate her hours. It calculates the total hours worked no problem (so long as they don't go pass midnight), but I wanted to also have it track overtime hours for her.

I have a formula that should work, but the problem is that if all the start and end times on a given day are both AM or both PM then it will not calculate the overtime hours no matter how much the total hours surpass 6 hours. However, as soon as you enter in a time value that starts at an AM time and ends at a PM time, such as 11:00 to 14:00, then it calculates the total overtime hours for the day just fine.

Here's a screenshot of the time sheet with times entered with total hours above 6, but no start and end time crossing from AM to PM:[image: bad outcome]

Here's an example where the the last time entered on the first day now goes from an AM time to a PM time. Notice that the overtime hours are now being calculated accurately. [image: good outcome]

The VBA generating the formulas that calculates the hours looks like this:

```
Sub calcHours(ByVal numDays As Integer)
    Dim newWeekRow As Integer: newWeekRow = 0

    With Sheets("timesheet")
        'Add the formula to calculate hours for the day
        Range(Cells(5, 17), Cells(numDays + 4, 17)).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUM((RC[-2] - RC[-3]) + (RC[-4] - RC[-5]) + (RC[-6] - RC[-7]) + (RC[-8] - RC[-9]) + (RC[-10] - RC[-11]) + (RC[-12] - RC[-13]))"

        'Add formula to calculate overtime hours
        Range(Cells(5, 19), Cells(numDays + 4, 19)).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-2]-(6/24) > 6/24, RC[-2]-(6/24), 0)"

        'Add the formula to calculate hours for the week
        For ctr = 1 To numDays
            If (Cells(4 + ctr, 2).Value = "Saturday") Then 'found the end of the week
                If (newWeekRow = 0) Then 'end of the first week
                    Cells(4 + ctr, 18).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R5C[-1]:RC[-1])"
                    newWeekRow = 4 + ctr
                Else
                    Cells(4 + ctr, 18).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-6]C[-1]:RC[-1])"
                    newWeekRow = 4 + ctr
                End If
            End If

            If (ctr = numDays) Then 'reached the end of the last week
                Cells(4 + ctr, 18).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R" & newWeekRow + 1 & "C[-1]:RC[-1])"
            End If
        Next ctr

        'Add formula to calulate total hours for the month
        With Cells(5 + numDays, 17)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" & numDays & "]C:R[-1]C)"
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use time in + date and time out + date and then use built-in Excel functions? If you combine the date and time in a single field, you could even use the (undocumented) DATEDIF function.

Comment: `"=IF(RC[-2]-(6/24) > 6/24, RC[-2]-(6/24), 0)"` is wrong. Use either `"=IF(RC[-2]-(6/24) > 0, RC[-2]-(6/24), 0)"` or `"=IF(RC[-2] > 6/24, RC[-2]-(6/24), 0)"`. Currently you are calculating for 12h overtime.

Comment: Why do you want to use VBA for this? I would create hidden helper columns for each time in/out pair then just sum them in the totals and subtract 6 hours from the total to get the overtime values...

Comment: DATEDIF is only for years, months or days but I'm looking for hours

Comment: @Tragamor I'm using VBA to dynamically generate the report with formulas. It starts with an empty template and a button to generate the report. It looks at the current date and generates the time sheet for whatever the current month is and automatically separates the weeks as well. There's also an input to override the date in case the user wants to generate a time sheet for a past or future month. I don't see how I could do this without VBA.

Comment: @VincentG Thanks, that worked, though I still don't understand why the way it was worked just as soon as a a single time in and time out pair went from AM to PM.

Comment: Having done a few of these "TIME CARDS" for various employers, some of the things you may want to consider is adding a column for regular hours.  Its an easy calc, but visually some people like to see it.  Also depending on where you are if its not written into the contract you may have local labour laws that have additional requirements over max number of hours a day.  you might find there is also a max per week and a max per month.

Comment: @Forward Ed thanks for the recommendations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your formula for suming the hours in the week is essentially:

```
=SUM(E5-D5,G5-F5,I5-H5,K5-J5,M5-L5, O5-N5)
```

The problem is that when you go past midnight you have no way of indicating that the time is the following day.  Since Time is stored as a decimal and date is stored as the integer, and by default, when only time is entered, 0 is the integer for the day.  All you need to do is add 1 to the time when they out time is less than the in time.  Going to cheat a bit and assume there will never be more than a 24 hour period between in and out.  So with that cheat in mind and that boolean True and False get converted to 1 and 0 respectively when going through a math operator, you could adjust your formula as follows:

```
=SUM(E5+(E5<D5)-D5,G5+(G5<F5)-F5,I5+(I5<H5)-H5,K5+(K5<J5)-J5,M5+(M5<L5)-L5, O5+(O5<N5)-N5)
```

Alternatively you could record the hours on the day they were worked on, not broken by the time you slept overnight as the delineater for the day.  Ie if you work from 2300 on monday to 0100 on tuesday, then record monday as time in 2300 and time out as 23:59, and Tuesday record time in as 00:00 and time out as 01:01. Note the added 1 minute to the time out.  This is to make up for the missing minute between 23:59 and 24:00 (which does not technically exist in excel but does work with some operations)

As for the overtime calculation see Vincent G's comment.  Another spin on that formula could be:

```
=MAX(Q5-6/24,0)
```

[image: POC]

You will need to change the cell references to match your VBA programming needs.  Both formulas correct overtime issue calculation and start and end time crossing midnight.

Comment: I'm afraid that your first suggestion did not work. Trying other suggestion now.

Comment: @Tom it may have been a conversion/typo when taking the above formula to VBA.  I added a screen shot to demonstrate that the formulas do work for times crossing midnight and calculating overtime hours.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you go over midnight, here's what I would do:

Going over midnight means the hours will be negative. In that case, do an IF statement where if the result is a negative number, simply add 24 hours (or 1 day) to the result.

Second, couldn't you calculate the overtime without VBA by simply subtracting 6 hours from total working hours for the day?
I'm not too familiar with VBA, so if I'm missing something blatantly obvious, please forgive me.

Comment: Thanks, using a conditional IF to multiple the answer by 1 when it goes overnight did work. As to why I'm using VBA, this is because the time sheet is being dynamically created. It looks at the current date and generates the time sheet for whatever the current month is and automatically separates the weeks as well. There's also an input to override the date in case the user wants to generate a time sheet for a past or future month. I don't see how I could do this without VBA.

Comment: I see, VBA for dynamic sheet creation is great. Unfortunately as I said, I don't understand that VBA code completely - so I'm just wondering if it's not possible to simply subtract 6 hours from calculated total working hours instead of that complex formula you have written? The problem is obviously elsewhere, but this seems like the easiest solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what's confusing. RC[-2]-(6/24) is the only way to subtract 6 hours from the total, but I only want to do that if the total hours have gone over 6. That's why it's in an IF statement that otherwise displays 0.

Comment: Okay, so I understand now - it's hours and relative cell position in that formula.
I think you're asking excel to print out overtime only if the overtime is bigger than 12 hours instead of 6. You have to ask it to print overtime when "RC[-2]-(6/24) > 0" (and not bigger than 6/24).
"=IF(RC[-2]-(6/24) > 0, RC[-2]-(6/24), 0)"

--P.S. it seems someone has already figured that out in the question comments

Comment: You're correct, and I updated my post acknowledging Vincent's solution a while ago.