# Excel Formula for finding the month end overtime summary

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2016

I am working on an overtime sheet where I summarize the overtime hours. Now I want to find the summary as a report.

For example table of the index contains 8 employers' names with their attendance and overtime hours. Therefore, I want to find this table as a report. It would be in docx file over the hyperlink with a formal report.

For more clear I attached a couple of images for more clarification.

[image]

Comment: your question is not clear enough. What exactly is the expected result / output? are you sure it's an excel formula you're looking for?

Comment: Yes Sir. For example, there will be a selection point that will be a summary. İf anyone clicks it then it will show the monthly summary  @YairMaron

Comment: What Yair ment is can you post actual data and expected result examples

Comment: Try to look at these example questions.. (it contains details/story/TriedFormula that allow others to help) [Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667987/calculating-overtime-hours-in-excel) [Example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43278784/specific-overtime-calculation) [Example3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56891418/formula-to-calculate-overtime-hours-not-working-consistently)

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/67373358/13607672 too - looks similar / repeat to pvs. Qs in this regard.